# Chrome.event.dispatch error in google chrome on executing a local web app

Tags: jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery

```
Error in event handler for 'undefined': TypeError: Cannot read property 'combi' of undefined
    at Object.bind (chrome-extension://libokbfffpaopdjmeofdfpmlanaenaje/js/lib/jquery.hotkeys-0.7.9.min.js:6:8)
    at chrome-extension://libokbfffpaopdjmeofdfpmlanaenaje/js/activate_hotkey.js:33:17
    at extension:102:9
    at [object Object].dispatch (event_bindings:200:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (miscellaneous_bindings:202:22) event_bindings:202 chrome.Event.dispatch
```

I would like to know, whether it is caused by my browser or my script is the cause.